# Ubuntu Boot Problem00

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

so I have a very depressing problem actually. I'm not sure what I have exactly done, but I'm pretty sure its within the limits of removing the Windows boot loader partition that remained after I completed wiped windows off my computer and replaced it with ubuntu.

After that, I accessed the BIOS, made it so I was able to boot from usb then proceeded to boot ubuntu from my usb drive in an attempt to add the free space that was available after the removal of that partition to my ubuntu partition (sda5).

Done all that, I remove the usb drive, reboot, and that's when I get an error saying I should go into advanced options in my BIOS and choose the correct boot device as it couldn't detect any from which it could boot from, I spent the last hour going through this forum since nothing could work and solve the problem for me. None of that worked, and Ubuntu completely disappeared from the boot menu options in the BIOS, I checked in GParted, the Ubuntu partition is STILL THERE with ALL the data and content, it's just, there is no way I could find it and use it as a boot option to boot from it, there's no trace of it in the BIOS.

I tried some of the answers I found here if not all of the available ones relating to this issue, I tried mounting it, I even got the partition I deleted back and still no luck, the only way I could now boot Ubuntu is from the usb drive, it wouldn't boot anything apart from something from a usb drive.

Have you guys ever faced such problem? Any answers relating to this issue would be greatly appreciated, as I don't want to re-install Ubuntu as I still have a lot of data/content on that Ubuntu partition and there's no way I could retrieve it after the installation.

It's an ASUS motherboard by the way if you're wondering. Thank you for your time!

Oh and, I almost forgot, when I checked on GParted, instead of ext4 it said efi for the Ubuntu partition, it's still that way, I tried changing it to ext4 and put '/' as the mount point, it changes but once I check again I find it hadn't changed, which is frankly weird and confusing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You did a lot of wrong things. Please also read http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/167850

Comment: I you don't want to dual-boot, just change UEFI to Legacy/CSM/BIOS mode. Reinstall Ubuntu erasing everything. Follow the post "How do I install Ubuntu?"

Comment: No guys, I already know how to install Ubuntu just fine, secure boot isn't an issue, Ubuntu is already installed, everything is fine regarding that matter, I dealt with all of those when I made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu.

The problem being in here is that Ubuntu completely vanished from the boot options in the BIOS, so I can't boot it.

Comment: Note that this isn't my first experience with Ubuntu, I've been using Ubuntu ever since the version 12.04 came out. So I'm not new to Ubuntu nor Linux, and no I'm not trying to dual boot, as I previously mentioned, I had completely removed Windows and replaced it all by Ubuntu. The problem that just popped up and the one that I had never dealt with before is Ubuntu vanishing from the BIOS as a boot option. So I'd greatly appreciate if we could focus on that problem instead of other irrelevant ones. Thank you.

Comment: Your details are a bit vague. Try booting an Ubuntu live CD and running the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (also available in the `boot-info-script` package). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL it provides here.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.